# How can I override css property?

Tags: html, css

Let say that I have a global `css` file, `global.css` :

```
.my-class {
    background-color:red;
}
```

And I need a specific `css` file, `specific.css`, just for a certain `html` file. And this `html` file also has `class` named `my-class`. In this time, however, I want to make this `html`'s background color as blue. How can I do that in `specific.css` file?

Comment: Add `.my-class {
    background-color:blue !important;
}` in your specific.css file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Option #1** is to make sure your `specific.css` file is included after your global one. this will cause the styles to overwrite.

For example:

```
<link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="specific.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Option #2** is to leverage CSS specificity.

See here for more info on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

**Option #3** is to use `!important` in your style that you want to take precedence.

This isn't highly recommended, but will work if the above two options fail to get you what you need.

Comment: Is that also works if those are components of bootstraps? I mean, `global.css` define `css`  for a certain bootstrap component and `specific.css` also define css of that component, too.

Comment: Yes will work regardless, just need to be named the same (or be even more specific (as mention in #2)) than the bootstraps and loaded after the bootstraps css.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the other element's `background-color` in a CSS file that was loaded AFTER `global.css` (e.g. load `specific.css` after `global.css` in your HTML markup). You can also use the `!important` tag to overwrite ALL other defined styles, but typically you won't need this. Its called **cascading** style sheets for a reason.